# "app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug" execution for this task whenever I try to run my Flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, androidx

Whenever I try to run my App, it always fails and it gives this error

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

I have been trying to resolve for some days but none of the solutions work.

I have tried to downgrade the versions of Firebase dependency, changed the minimum sdk version and many other things which were available on the Internet. Probably it is a version problem for the firebase dependency but I couldn't get a hold of that.

This is my **pubspec.yaml** file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  url_launcher: ^4.0.2
  dio: any
  path_provider: any
  carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1
  sqflite: any
  #cloud_firestore: ^0.7.4
  firebase_database: ^3.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.2.2
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.4
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.0
```

This is the **app/build.gradle file** in which some changes were to be made for the solution but which didn't work. I haven't added the complete file but just some parts which are essential.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.technothlon.techno_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My **build.gradle** file

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

I have tried these workarounds:

1. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23929
2. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23131

And some other solutions as well from Stack and Github but nothing helped me up. Personally I believe that the problem lies with the **Firebase dependency version** and its compatibililty with **AndroidX**.

Screenshot of the error: https://ibb.co/G2sXnpx

It would be great if someone can help me on this because I couldn't get my head around this problem for over 5 days now :( .

Comment: check by changing minSdkVersion to 19 or 21, I faced a similar issue like this and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer by @Filled Stacks didn't fix your issue the problem is in AndroidX and deprecated support libs conflicts in your Flutter app.

as per Flutter docs:

> AndroidX can break a Flutter app at compile time in two ways:
>
> 1. The app uses an AndroidX plugin and its main build.gradle file has a compileSdkVersion below version 28.
> 2. The app uses both deprecated and AndroidX code at the same time.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Long story short:
you either [migrate](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#how-to-migrate-a-flutter-app-to-androidx) to AndroidX the whole app or you go through all dependencies and make sure they are all based on Android support libs and not AndroidX.

No silver bullets this time, sorry.

As you can see in [this list of popular AndroidX-free libs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx)  they all are pretty outdated. So I'd recommend migrating to AndroidX unless you have a key lib which is based on deprecated support libs and can't be replaced.

Answer (score -2):

In your app/build.gradle file you're indicating that you want to use multidex in the default config with

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

But you don't have multidex as a dependency. Add under your dependencies

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work too. It gave the same error as before.